# Js script works on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

So the js code is fetching json data from local api and displaying data in tabular format, everything works on desktop but shows no data on mobile. I tried everything but there is something wrong with this js code.

I don't understand what is wrong, the rest of the html page is loading perfectly fine on mobile. Is there any changes I should make in code.

```
function getUrl(start = 0) {
    return 'http://localhost/login_registration_system_LAMP/api.php';
}
function getData(url) 
{
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => loadDataIntoTable(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function loadDataIntoTable(data) {
    let coinprodName = [];
    let coinprice = [];
    let coinper = [];
    let coinPerson = [];
    let coinphone = [];
    let coinsize = [];
    let coinbrand = [];
    let coinspecial = [];
    let coinlife = [];
    let coinmoq = [];

    data.forEach((coin) => {
        coinprodName.push(coin.product_name);
        coinprice.push(coin.price);
        coinper.push(coin.per);
        coinPerson.push(coin.person_name);
        coinphone.push(coin.phone);
        coinsize.push(coin.size);
        coinbrand.push(coin.brand);
        coinspecial.push(coin.special);
        coinlife.push(coin.life);
        coinmoq.push(coin.moq);
    });

    let tableBody = document.getElementById('crypto-table-body');

    let html = "";

    for(let i = 0; i < coinmoq.length; i++) {
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<td>" + coinprodName[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinprice[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinper[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinPerson[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinphone[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinsize[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinbrand[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinspecial[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinlife[i] + "</td>";
        html += "<td>" + coinmoq[i] + "</td>";
        
        
        html += "</tr>";
    }

    tableBody.innerHTML = html;
}

function init() {
    const url = getUrl();
    getData(url);
}

init();
```

[screenshot of phone and desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnEsH.png)

[screenshot of phone and desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adFbu.jpg)

Comment: You'll need to debug your mobile browser; the way you do that depends on the browser and OS of the browser, but you should be able to get a console showing errors that are thrown when you run the JavaScript on your mobile browser. Provide those errors and someone can tell you conclusively what the problem is, rather than the guesses currently being thrown out.

Comment: Have you tried using Inspector (F12) and looking at the elements as you shrink the window from full size to mobile-sized? It could be a problem with your responsive theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make server and consumes it from another device, please use internal ip like `192.168.1.X` to point that.

Example:
In the same network you using a desktop and a mobile phone, well, the desktop have internal ip `192.168.1.2` and you phone `192.168.1.3`.

So when you using `getUrl` function:

```
function getUrl(start = 0) {
    return 'http://192.168.1.2/login_registration_system_LAMP/api.php';
}
```

And... if you phone is not in the same network, well, you need using other tools like "noIp", ngrok, ...

**Tip:**

Whats about CORS?
well, if you don't send cors headers, you phone can't consume you API.
Please, check this:

```php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: I did the some, the website is working fine. But this js uses to display table, the table is not visible on phone but visible on desktop

Comment: whats about cors?

Comment: Added CORS header in API, please check the screen shots.

Comment: well, can you share the output of console javascript from you phone? connect you phone to the desktop(via usb) and open you chrome with this url `chrome://inspect/#devices`

Answer (score 2):

It's because of you are using `localhost` on mobile, use something like this https://ngrok.com/

`localhost` is a hostname that refers to the current computer used to access it. So on your mobile, there is no `localhost`.

You can use `ngrok` after install as follow,

`ngrok http 80`

Comment: I was accessing the website via ip in localhost, that is not the issue. Other components of websites are working fine

Comment: You can find the ip `hostname -I`. As long they are both connected to the same wifi it should work.

Comment: Added screenshots of the problem

Comment: @thethird3y3 Check your console and post if there any errors on it.